# How to remove KDE Plasma-Desktop?

Tags: kde

I recently switched to ubuntu 14.04 and installed KDE plasma-desktop environment using this command :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop
```

...And now , after using it for few minutes ,i want to delete it.I have tried to remove it through this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove plasma-desktop
```

but it still appears in the login options.....``

Comment: `plasma-desktop` is a metapackage: one that just points to others to install. I believe the way to remove KDE is to run `sudo apt-get purge plasma-*`, but please be careful and make sure the remove list mainly has packages that involve KDE.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

this worked for me

```
sudo apt-get remove plasma-desktop kubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get remove dolphin
```

Comment: Note that even after `autoremove`, there will still be some applications left over from KDE Plasma. For example, you might find that Konsole is still installed.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was having audio issues with KDE where the Audio settings were not showing up. Installing kubuntu-desktop installed the required missing packages and now my sound is back. I was actually about to remove it

Answer (score 1):

## First, check what is going to be removed

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep .kde.
```

## If you are ok with it, run this command

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge kde*
```

## Command explanation

```
# dpkg -l       lists all installed packages
# grep .kde.    filters, so that only packages with keyword kde within their names, listed
# purge         removes mentioned package
# autoremove    tries to remove dependency packages
```